# How do you sort elements underneath a project during Eclipse Plugin Development?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I have an Eclipse(CDT) plugin which provides two custom nodes in the root of a certain type of project in the Project Explorer.

For some reason one of the nodes shows up at the very top of the nodes underneath the project while the other is at the bottom between the folders and the files.  I can change the label on these nodes and it does not change anything.

Is there a way to add a sorter (kind of like commonSorter for the nodes underneath my custom nodes) for re-ordering things directly underneath a project?

Answer (score 0):

While not the exact solution you can put the ID of another navigatorContent item in the "appearsBefore" property of your navigatorContent item.  This will force your custom nodes to appear before another navigatorContent.

A more complete solution may involve using the "sortOnly" method but for now this works for me (and is probably faster).